# I got some signal problems when I attempt to spawn multiple nodes

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

My intend is to spawn node (I will say Stickman for now) on a specific position and make them move to left and right using buttons.

[image]

As you can see, I have two buttons to move my Stickman. The Attack button will move the Stickman to the right, while the Defense button will move it to the left. The small button from the right is used to spawn the stickman.

[image: Thing works like a charm, yes]

> Things work like a charm, yes

The issues occurs when I try to spawn another Stickman. For some reasons the signal is cut with the second Stickman, which I believed is because I only connected my signal to Stickman's node, but in this case its currently rename as Stickman2, Stickman3 and so on.

[image: Problem shows up]

> The problem reveals itself

Here is the code of my stickman:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed = 30
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
onready var enemy_base = get_node("../Position/enemy_base").global_position
onready var allied_base = get_node("../Position/allied_base").global_position

enum {
    ATTACK, 
    DEFENSE, 
    RETREAT
}

var state = DEFENSE

func _physics_process(delta):
    match state:
        ATTACK:
            attack(delta)
            
        DEFENSE:
            defense(delta)
        
func attack(delta):
    var direction = (enemy_base - global_position).normalized()
    var desired_velocity = direction * speed
    var steering = (desired_velocity - velocity) * delta * 2.5
    velocity += steering
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
    
func defense(delta):
    var direction = (allied_base - global_position).normalized()
    var desired_velocity = direction * speed
    var steering = (desired_velocity - velocity) * delta * 2.5
    velocity += steering
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func _on_Attack_pressed():
    state = ATTACK

func _on_Defense_pressed():
    state = DEFENSE
```

And this is the spawning code I used:

```
extends Node2D

var Stickboi = preload("res://StickBoy.tscn")
var Swordman = Swordman

func _on_StickBoi_pressed():
    Swordman = Stickboi.instance()
    Swordman.global_position = $Position/behind_allied_base.global_position
    add_child(Swordman)

func _on_Attack_pressed():
    Swordman.state = Swordman.ATTACK
    
func _on_Defense_pressed():
    Swordman.state = Swordman.DEFENSE
```

I want all my Stickmans to react to my signal whenever I pressed the Attack or Defense buttons, which in this case doesn't work at all. I really appreciate if you have any ideas that could share, even if its just a hint. I'm still a beginner and I acknowledge my stupidity, so sorry to ask such simple question and also my bad English grammars. Please ask if there are anything you want to know in case my explanation is such simple, I will try my best to answer as fast as possible. Once again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you connect the signals.

Instead, it appears to me, that the signals are connected to the `Node2D` that has the spawning code. And it calls into the `Swordman` instance, which is the last instance it created.

---

You can actually `connect` the signals.

*I'm guessing that the `Node2D` that has the spawning code is the parent of the buttons.*

First of all, you will have no need to keep a reference to the instance. Nor will you connect the buttons to the `Node2D` that has the spawning code. I'm getting rid of that:

```
extends Node2D

var Stickboi = preload("res://StickBoy.tscn")

func _on_StickBoi_pressed():
    var swordman = Stickboi.instance()
    swordman.global_position = $Position/behind_allied_base.global_position
    add_child(swordman)
```

Instead we are going to connect the buttons to the instance (you seem to have conveniently created methods for that, so I'll use them).

```
extends Node2D

var Stickboi = preload("res://StickBoy.tscn")

func _on_StickBoi_pressed():
    var swordman = Stickboi.instance()
    $Attack.connect("pressed", swordman, "_on_Attack_pressed")
    $Defense.connect("pressed", swordman, "_on_Defense_pressed")
    swordman.global_position = $Position/behind_allied_base.global_position
    add_child(swordman)
```

And that should work.